# Suurballe's algorithm for k-best

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm interesting in adapting Suurballe's algorithm to find the best K paths from a source to destination instead of just the two best.  I think people do it all the time but I've been searching for hours and can't find a paper that explains it clearly.  There's a reference to a  paper on the Suurballe's wikipedia page that talks about it, but it gives no detail on the extension past the first two (how the graph is modified and results merged, etc.).  Incidentally, I'm actually working on the vertex-disjoint problem, not the edge disjoint problem spelled out on wikipedia.

My concise question: How do you extend Suurballe's algorithm beyond two paths?

Comment: It would be helpful to include a few links in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In the literature this is called the successive shortest paths problem, and it works in essentially the same way, just repeated. You modify each discovered path's weights in the same way as you modified the first.

Comment: Thanks.  How about the merging part though?  Do I fully solve the two-path problem before moving on, or do I continue to make "raw" paths from the modified graphs and then somehow merge them all at the end?  By "merging" I mean the step where the raw paths from the modified graphs are resolved into viable, disjoint paths.  hope that makes sense.

Comment: The cuts should be made sequentially, I believe.  That's why the SSP problem is non-polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The Suurballe algorithm is for finding the two edge-disjoint paths with minimum total length. The Suurballe algorithm can't be extended to more then two edges.

The k-shortest path problem is a different problem. Here the shortest paths are

Comment: It looks as if this got submitted before you were able to finish your thought?